# How to generate a random binary tree of given height h?

Tags: tree, binary-tree, random-testing

I am learning to implement tree algorithms and often I need to test my algorithms by generating different binary tree, which i do manually. I tried writing functions for it but it will not generate all possible trees. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: specify programming language

Comment: python, java or c++ will do the job.

Comment: for given n number of nodes the number of binary trees is equal Catalan number of 2*n+1 which is very large. generating all possible tree for even n > 15 is computationally very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

if you use Python, maybe the `binarytree` module is what you need

```
>>> from binarytree import tree
>>> t = tree(height=3)
>>> t.pprint()

         _______8_____
        /             \
    ___3___            2
   /       \          / \
  14       _4       _5   12
 /  \     /  \     /       \
6    7   10   0   13        11
```